# Use unique ID with querySelector in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<video width="840" data-id="#{{$index}}">
    <source src="{{box.video}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

And I've got this scope for videos:

```
<script>
    video = document.querySelector("[data-id]");
    function playVideo() {
      video.play();
    }
    function stopVideo() {
      video.pause();
    }
    function pauseVideo() {
      video.pause();
    }
    function skip(value) {
      video.currentTime += value;
    }      
 </script>
```

I clicked first video then its ok, working good. But when I click another video, it shows first video again. Data ID should be unique in script.
How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: from where {{$index}} coming??

Comment: If I try with querySelector(''{{$index}}), its getting synthax error.

Comment: Show your complete code

Answer (score 1):

You're just selecting the first object that has the `[data-id]` attribute. Which will natually be the same element every time. Instead you need to do something like this:

```
video = document.querySelector("[data-id='" + yourIndex + "']");
```